# group by on terms_id if we have multiple columns on select query

Tags: sql-server

My Requirement is to group by `TERMS_ID` only, but still be able to see many `TERMS_ID` numbers. Here I am looking to group all the records done on particular day on based on `TERMS_ID`.

Looking for some inputs.

```
SELECT FL.TERMS_ID,FR.CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC,

((FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6) +
(FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7)) AS "CASH DISB",

FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 AS "DENOM 1" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0 AS "AMT DISBURSED1",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 AS "DENOM 2" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1 AS "AMT DISBURSED2",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 AS "DENOM 3" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2 AS "AMT DISBURSED3",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 AS "DENOM 4" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3 AS "AMT DISBURSED4",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 AS "DENOM 5" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4 AS "AMT DISBURSED5",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 AS "DENOM 6" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5 AS "AMT DISBURSED6",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 AS "DENOM 7" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6 AS "AMT DISBURSED7",
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 AS "DENOM 8" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7 AS "AMT DISBURSED8"

FROM SSPNGT.LOG_LIST201706 AS FL
JOIN SSPNGT.LOG_RECORD201706 AS FR ON FL.TSTAMP_TRANS=FR.TSTAMP_TRANS 
WHERE FR.TSTAMP_TRANS LIKE'20170622%'
GROUP BY FL.TERMS_ID,FR.CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC,
FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7,
FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7;
```

**Results:**

```
TERMS_ID    CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC  CASH DISB  --------
    ------------------------------------------------
    TERM101   BANGALORE-1            150       --------
    TERM101   BANGALORE-1            170       --------   
    TERM101   BANGALORE-1            500       --------
    TERM200   CHENNAI-1              300       --------
    TERM200   CHENNAI-1              200       --------
    TERM301   CHENNAI-21              600       --------
    TERM301   CHENNAI-21              200       --------
    TERM301   CHENNAI-21              100       --------
```

I am looking for the below result:

```
TERMS_ID    CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC  CASH DISB  --------
    ------------------------------------------------
    TERM101   BANGALORE-1            820       --------
    TERM200   CHENNAI-1              500       --------
    TERM301   CHENNAI-21             900       --------
```

Answer (score 0):

you ca use SUM() function of sql-server

```
SELECT FL.TERMS_ID,FR.CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC,
    SUM
    (
    ((FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6) +
    (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7)) 
    )
    AS "CASH DISB",

    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 AS "DENOM 1" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0 AS "AMT DISBURSED1",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 AS "DENOM 2" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1 AS "AMT DISBURSED2",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 AS "DENOM 3" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2 AS "AMT DISBURSED3",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 AS "DENOM 4" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3 AS "AMT DISBURSED4",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 AS "DENOM 5" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4 AS "AMT DISBURSED5",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 AS "DENOM 6" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5 AS "AMT DISBURSED6",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 AS "DENOM 7" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6 AS "AMT DISBURSED7",
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 AS "DENOM 8" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7 AS "AMT DISBURSED8"

    FROM SSPNGT.LOG_LIST201706 AS FL
    JOIN SSPNGT.LOG_RECORD201706 AS FR ON FL.TSTAMP_TRANS=FR.TSTAMP_TRANS 
    WHERE FR.TSTAMP_TRANS LIKE'20170622%'
    GROUP BY FL.TERMS_ID,FR.CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC,
    FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7,
    FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7;
```

Comment: @Mdhar9e did this helped you or you were looking for something else

Comment: no Ashu, not worked. I am looking to group on 'TERMS_ID'

Comment: could you please post the output of my answer and tell where is it getting wrong

Comment: CASH_DISB column amount is getting doubled for each TERMS_ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that it runs fine, I wouldn't mess with (and break) your original query. So I would leave it as it is, as your data source, and just group its results by terms_id.

```
with MY_DATA as 
(
  SELECT FL.TERMS_ID,FR.CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC,

  ((FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6) +
  (FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7)) AS "CASH DISB",

  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 AS "DENOM 1" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0 AS "AMT DISBURSED1",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 AS "DENOM 2" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1 AS "AMT DISBURSED2",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 AS "DENOM 3" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2 AS "AMT DISBURSED3",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 AS "DENOM 4" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3 AS "AMT DISBURSED4",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 AS "DENOM 5" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4 AS "AMT DISBURSED5",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 AS "DENOM 6" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5 AS "AMT DISBURSED6",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 AS "DENOM 7" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6 AS "AMT DISBURSED7",
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 AS "DENOM 8" ,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7 * FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7 AS "AMT DISBURSED8"

  FROM SSPNGT.LOG_LIST201706 AS FL
  JOIN SSPNGT.LOG_RECORD201706 AS FR ON FL.TSTAMP_TRANS=FR.TSTAMP_TRANS 
  WHERE FR.TSTAMP_TRANS LIKE'20170622%'
  GROUP BY FL.TERMS_ID,FR.CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC,
  FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE0,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE1,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE2,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE3,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE4,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE5,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE6,FR.BOX_ITEM_VALUE7,
  FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP0,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP1,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP2,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP3,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP4,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP5,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP6,FR.BOX_NO_ITEMS_DISP7
)

select TERMS_ID, CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC, sum(CASH DISB) as CASH_DIB
from MY_DATA
group by TERMS_ID, CCARD_ACPT_NAME_LOC
```

By the results that you have published, this has to return the result that you need.

Comment: @Mdhar9e remember to let us know what solution solves your problem.